# One of my object changes color after animation rendering

Tags: rendering, animation, color

This is what it looks like when I rendered an image of my final work [image: Image rendering]

But after I rendered animation on it, the donut's changed color. [image: Animation rendering]

I'm new to Blender, I'm following the tutorial on Youtube for this project.

Can someone tell me the possible solution for this? I want it to look like the first image when it is rendered in animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually blender uses the color fuchsia for indicating that textures are missing, if I remember correctly he uses a texture to the doughnut. Your texture of the doughnut must be saved in a directory and added as a image texture for your doughnut in the shader editor.

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem, I saved the doughnut texture file in a different path location. So, by putting the doughnut texture file and the final work (the 2nd image above) in the same file path location will solve the problem. It is a very simple mistake that I did when organizing the file. Thank you for your help